# Printing list along with string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list as below:

```
x = ['jasmine', 'amine']
```

I want output like this:

```
Did you mean jasmine or amine ?
```

Which means I have to concatenate a string and the list.
However, the only method that I know is just to print the list using the * or .join method as shown below:

```
print(' , '.join(x))
print(*x)

output:
jasmine, amine
jasmine amine
```

Is there a way that I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: `print("Did you mean {} or {} ?".format(x[0], x[1]))`

Comment: Since you brought up the `*` operator, you can also do: `print('Did you mean {} or {} ?'.format(*x))`

Answer (score 0):

You can print with

```
print("Did you mean {} or {} ?".format(x[0], x[1]))
```

Comment: @Jaimin, please mark my answer as the correct one, if you found if the solution you were looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `.join` method that you already know:

```
print("Did you mean " + ", or ".join(x) + "?")
```

This will handle arbitrarily long lists.

Comment: Yes. This will definitely help me in future as my fuctionality will have a long list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Did you mean " + x[0] + " or " + x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use `+` to concatenate string:

```
 print('Did you mean ' + x[0] + ' or ' + x[1] +' ?')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = ['jasmine', 'amine']
print('did you mean ' + x[0] + ' or ' + x[1] + '?')
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Did you mean %s or %s ?" %(x[0], x[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Did you mean "+str(x[0])+"or"+str(x[1])+" ?")
```

That's it, if you have any question ask me ;)